# Apache Commons Configuration file location

Tags: java, apache

In my web application I wanted to use apache commons configuration.
The file is available in the classes of war file, but it's not able to read saying cannot locate the file. Could some one help me with an example?

Comment: Reworded for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

In a Servlet, you should be able to reach your configuration file using that king of code:

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
String confFilePath = context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/classes/my.conf");
File file = new File(confFilePath);
System.out.println("My conf. file is here: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
```